# "ls" is not listing any user's under /home directory in Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, login, users

Am very new to Ubuntu and I got a machine which was used by some one before. Now I don't know how to recover login credentials.

I tried to enter to root and tried to see the user names. I used ls `/home`,but am not seing any users or names displayed. Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?if you want to reset password of admin read http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/184942

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /home`?

Comment: Could you please add more in-detail as how you've managed to logg into the system? Also, please paste an output of `/etc/passwd` only if possible.

Comment: That system you got is 2nd hand. So the previous owner deleted his own user resulting in no users on that system. The answer is correct: just re-create a user as -root- and than make this a sudo user.

Comment: I agree it's most likely the original owner deleted any previous accounts - but isn't it _possible_ that the system has a separate /home partition that's not mounted when in recovery mode? The /etc/passwd file should confirm which.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to simply add a new user. Have you tried to do the following commands?

```
sudo useradd -m username
sudo passwd username
```

Replace `username` with a an account name.

The `-m` in the useradd adds a folder in the home directory. Maybe the last user used a location other than the home directory for users but I recommend sticking with the way it's "supposed" to be done.

Comment: He also has to make that user part of sudo otherwise he would have no admin account.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question. Just use askubuntu.com/q/24006/184942  as aditya suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the post from John Smith and after that try typing the below command,

> ls -al

and check and revert back with your feedback